# What is the level of generality of the bias-variance tradeoff?

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning

I have just learned about the "bias-variance tradeoff" in machine learning, in the context of it being applied to simple regression models.

Now I am wondering: is this tradeoff a general universal principle that is applicable to every (conceivable) learning algorithm, or is it specific to particular algorithms, like regression?